# SQL redshift select whole table or one record dynamic select question

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-order-by, amazon-redshift

I have a table and I want to have dynamic select:

select the whole table if condition column doesn't have any 'bad' value.

if there's any 'bad', then print the rows that has bad value instead.

```
id, name, condition
1    apple     good
2    pearl     bad
3    kiwi      good
4    grapes    good
```

I thought about use union, but couldn't think it through how to select correctly.

If the table is like this, then print the whole table

```
id, name, condition
1    apple     good
2    pearl     good
3    kiwi      good
4    grapes    good
```

If the table is like this, then select row 3 only

```
id, name, condition
1    apple     good
2    pearl     good
3    kiwi      bad
4    grapes    good
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option is `union all` and `not exists`:

```
select t.* from mytable t where condition = 'bad'
union all 
select t.* from mytable t where not exists (select 1 from mytable t1 where t1.condition = 'bad')
```

If you are running SQL Server (which you tagged, along with amazon-redshift), you could also do this `top 1 with ties`:

```
select top (1) with ties t.*
from mytable t
order by case when condition = 'bad' then 0 else 1 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `not exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where not exists (select 1 from t t2 where t2.condition = 'bad');
```